# C#: Interface to force list of items inheriting the interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following interface:

```
IMyInterface
{
     IList<IMyInterface> MyList { get; set; }
     int X { get; set; }
     int Y { get; set; }
}
```

I want to force the class implementing this interface to have a list "MyList" with a list of other items also implementing IMyInterface. How do I do this?

I get errors if I try the following:

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interface forces that itself. That's the difference between interface and abstract class. Its a contract and you are Forced to obey that.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: are you trying to have list of all types who implements your interface?

Comment: Do you mean that you want `MyList` to only have items of the implementing class type?  If so you'll need to make the interface generic.

Comment: You get errors because you're trying to make a List of MyClass, not IMyInterface. Interfaces don't work like that.

Comment: Updated question sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the items of `MyList` to be of the implementing type class you have to use generics.  You should also use a restraint to force `T` to be a type that implements the interface.  And `MyList` still has to be a `IList` in the implementing class.

```
IMyInterface<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
     IList<T> MyList { get; set; }
     int X { get; set; }
     int Y { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass: IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public IList<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't stop someone from doing something like

```
public class AnotherClass: IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public IList<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

But it's as close as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    IList<T> MyList { get; set; }
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public IList<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can go for something like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    List<T> MyList { get; }
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> MyList { get; }
}
```

I would actually prefer for my interface to not define setter for MyList since only getter is required from outside as you most like would like to implement logic of getting items to this list within MyClass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are what you want but still you cannot FORCE the user to do. You are only forcing user that the implementing class will be implementing IMyInterface and I can still do

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
    IList<T> MyList { get; set; }
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public IList<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public IList<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Here `FooBar` satisfies all the rules, still `MyList` is of Type `IList<MyClass>` but not of type `ILIst<FooBar>`.